# Invoke command line as in a batch script

Tags: tcl

I have this batch file with command:

```
xyz.exe -parm1 path1/a.wav > path2/a.txt
```

How can this command be executed in TCL script, so that *xyz.exe* when called with arguments as *parm1* and input path *path1* of wav file *a.wav*, produces op that is redirected to *a.text* file in *path2*?

I have very basic TCL knowledge, but I couldn't find way of redirection.
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl's [`exec` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) knows how to redirect command output into a file. You can just do this:

```
exec xyz.exe -parm1 path1/a.wav > path2/a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working as below:

```
set ip_pth path1/a.wav
set op_pth path2/a.txt
set lf [open $op_pth w]
puts $lf [exec xyz.exe -parm1 $ip_pth]
close $lf
```